# Can one saint be more intellectual than the other?

Tags: rishi, saint

Generally people don't compare the intellects of saints. But sometimes when they talk about them, they say great saints. What does it mean by great saints?

1. Does any saint has high intellect or know more about the Supreme being over the other?
2. If every enlightened saint has experienced the bliss then why does intellect vary between saints?
3. Do they have more enthusiasm to experience the supreme being?
4. Do they love the supreme being more than others?
5. Do they be in samadhi for more time than the others?

Take Vyasa Maharshi for example, he is the Guru of the Gurus, the greatest saint living. In a similar cadre are Patanjali, the Sapta Rishis etc.

All saints achieve the thoughtless state and in the state everyone are one and the same. Then why does some saints have more intellect. Is it true to say so?

Comment: If by saint you mean God-realized saint (because technically even a sadhaka who is still in practice is also a saint) the every saint is one and the same. they have experienced their true inner nature. However they do not show it out. They are no longer under any kind of need to 'show off' their knowledge to others. Their focus is on acting as per the Will of God. Thus while all saints have realized the Truth, different saints have different mission in their message. For example, Ramana Maharishi propagated Absolute Knowledge/Self-inquiry, while Sri Mahaprabhu propagated Name chanting/Bhakti.

Comment: I don't get this question at all and hence I'll be closing. Please ask questions which helps other who are searching for the same, the question of yours will fetch biased opinion based answers. Obviously not all will be intellectually same.

Comment: @Mr.Alien But everyone have realized the God, then how does their intellect vary?

Comment: @JavaTechnical It is only that a few of these "God-realized" souls choose to take human form to impart knowledge as Gurus (such realized incarnations are Iswara kOTi whereas we are jIva kOti). Those others who have not verbalized their knowledge are no less intellectual.

Comment: This is a valid question, @Mr.Alien, please reopen.