# How can one become a Brahmarishi?

Tags: ramayana, rishi

Who coined the term *Brahmarishi*? How can one become a Brahmarishi?

Does a Brahmarishi know the future? A lot of rishi's in Ramayana seem to know the purpose of Rama's birth, how is that they know this?

I have more questions like the ones asked [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/can-one-saint-be-more-intellectual-than-the-other), but not quite sure why it was closed (some of the comments to that question could very well be answers)

Comment: Vishwamitra's path to becoming a Brahmarishi is described in the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana.  But I'm not sure what scripture talks about the concept of Brahmarishis more generally.