# How can a brahmin attain powers in Kaliyuga similar to the Trikala Gnana brahmarshi's or Saptharishi's in other yugas?

Tags: brahman, rishi, kali-yuga, brahmins

How can a brahmin attain powers in Kaliyuga similar to the power of Trikala Gnana brahmarshi's or Saptharishi's in other yugas?

Examples: Vasishta, Agasthya, Atri, Gautama, Kashyapa, Bharadvaja, Durvasa, Jamadagni, Bhrigu, Parashara, Vyasa, Koushika, Suta etc.

How can a Brahmin live and lead a family life in the path of Saptharishi's in Kaliyuga without income/money?

Comment: I corrected grammar mistakes for you.

Comment: "How can a Brahmin live and lead a family life in the path of Saptharishi's in Kaliyuga without income/money?" It is virtually impossible to live without money in the Kaliyuga.

Comment: Very related or a duplicate of [How can one become a Brahmarishi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8881/5212)

Comment: If one's turiya(racial purity, original state of all Brahmins(atleast ancestors of previous generations), as well as we have endowed with any siddhis, our ancestors possessed from birth, though through if eating non sattvic western junk food, meat, fraudulent Allopathy which directly attacks our soma so that our soma sealed away, aura become weak, vulnerable to negative energy, committing miscagney, as well as falling victim to poisoned food, black magic, one devolves, falls to lowest heights), they can easily live without food, water whenever they want.

Comment: As well as vayu gaman siddhi changes air/ether to money, and if a turiya Brahmin chants kanakadhara with devotion, Laxmi might actually appear, and shower jewels or gold, just like she did to Shankaracharya. Saraswat Brahmins are definitely turiya BTW. Though, as long as they have not did any of above sins I've mentioned,that is.

Answer (score 2):

A saint does not bother whether powers have been acquired in the process of attaining the ABSOLUTE BLISS.  If it is the prArabdha of the Saint to attain powers, they will evolve within him/her.

---

Brahmarshi/Saint, or whatever name you may give to the **REALISED ONE**, does not bother to acquire any money to live on.

The Saints like Sage Vasistha, Viswamitra, etc, of that era or Sages like Sri Ramana Maharshi of our era will not have EGO or desires to acquire riches to live on.  Their mind will be lost and they will remain merged in **the GOD/ABSOLUTE BLISS**.

**The God will take care of those saints and provide profession/money/other materials, as required to the family, if they have one.**

---

The following is an excerpt from **Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi**

> Sri Bhagavan once recounted how Kavyakantha Ganapathi Muni asked Him:
> My own opinion is that a man can live on Rs. 3 a month. What is Sri
> Bhagavan’s opinion in the matter?
>
> M.: A man can live happily only if he knows that he requires nothing
> wherewith to live.
>
> Page 536 from https://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Ramana-Maharshi-Talks-with-Ramana-Maharshi-3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In Kaliyuga, people are shortlived and lack Dharma and true Gurus, as powers like Astras and Siddhis were passed on from gurus to disciples in Gurukuls and Ashramas. Gurukuls were burned and scholars there were either killed or forced to work for Britishers or Mughals under foreign invasion. Most of the scholars and Gurus are hypocrites today and true Dharma has been corrupted by western education and adoption of western civilization and their language.

[Srimad Bhagavatam](http://bhagavata.org/canto12/chapter1.html)
The Degraded Dynasties and Corrupt Nature of the Rulers of Kali-yuga

> (1) S'rî S'uka said: 'And then, oh King, under the strong influence of
>   the time [of Kali-yuga] religiousness, truthfulness, cleanliness,
>   tolerance and mercy as also duration of life, physical strength and
>   memory will diminish day after day [see also 1.16]. (2) Among the
>   people of the age of Kali all one attains by good birth, behavior and
>   qualities will be wealth while material power will be the only factor
>   determining what is just and reasonable. (3) Relations between men and
>   women will be based upon sensual pleasure, business will be ruled by
>   deceit, masculinity and femininity are there for sexual attraction and
>   **a sacred thread will suffice to be considered learned Brahmin.** (4) **External marks only determine someone's spiritual status and constitute the basis for mutual exchanges, because of a lack of funds
>   one is less credible and scholarship consists of word jugglery.** (5)
>   Poverty simply means a lack of virtue and hypocrisy and deceit are the
>   standard of virtue; verbal agreement is enough to be married and a
>   bath suffices to start the day. (6) **A holy place is a reservoir of
>   water somewhere far away**, beauty depends on one's hair style, life's
>   purpose is to fill one's belly, someone audacious is considered
>   truthful, when one can maintain a family one is an expert and one
>   observes religious principles for the sake of one's reputation. (7)
>   With the earth being crowded with a populace thus corrupted, anyone
>   who is the strongest among the intellectuals, the rulers, the
>   merchants and the working class, will be called the king. (8) The
>   citizens whose wives and property are stolen by a merciless and
>   avaricious ruling class that behaves like ordinary thieves, will flee
>   to the mountains and the forests. (9) Suffering draughts, famine and
>   taxation they will be ruined and resort to the consumption of leaves,
>   roots, meat, honey, fruits, flowers and seeds [see also 1.16: 20,
>   4.20: 14, 4.21: 24, B.G. 3: 14]. (10) Plagued by cold, wind, heat, rain and snow as also by quarrels, hunger, thirst and diseases, they
>   suffer a great deal of distress and anxiety. (11) The maximum duration
>   of life for human beings in Kali-yuga will be fifty years. (12-16)
>   When the bodies of all living entities are in decay from the
>   contamination of Kali-yuga, when the dutifulness of the members of all
>   status-orientations is lost, when the Vedic path for all man has
>   changed into a predominantly atheistic sense of duty, when the kings
>   mainly consist of thieves and the people in their various occupations
>   are lying criminals of useless violence [against specially animals],
>   when the societal classes as good as all are engaged in profit-minded
>   labor, cows have the same value as goats, the hermitages hardly can be
>   distinguished from materialistic households, family bonds do not reach
>   beyond the ties of marriage, when the plants and herbs are mostly
>   small sized and all trees are like s'amî trees, when there is always
>   lightning in the clouds and the homes are ruled by loneliness
>   [voidism, impersonalism, see Pranâti], when Kali-yuga is running at
>   its end and the people behave like asses, the Supreme Lord will
>   descend in the mode of pure goodness to defend the dharma.